# CMake: How to add dependency on linker script for executable

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake script where the final executable is linked with my own linker script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(test_app)

set(LINKER_SCRIPT "linker.ld")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -T ${LINKER_SCRIPT}")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf
    main.cpp
    startup.cpp
)
```

How do I make an executable dependent also on the linker script file (trigger linking if `linker.ld` was changed)?

Comment: How is this script produced? `add_custom_target()`?

Comment: Linker script is edited by hand, at this time if I make changes in this script, then I must re-build project.

Comment: I try to add this: `add_custom_target(OUTPUT ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf DEPENDS ${LINKER_SCRIPT})` but without success.

Comment: Ah, you want CMake to rebuild executable if linker script was changed?

Comment: See [LINK_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/LINK_DEPENDS.html) target property. This works for all `makefile` generators except - until now - for Ninja (will be fixed with CMake 3.4, see [0014796: LINK_DEPENDS should work with Ninja backend](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14796))

Comment: Florian, look like this is the right way and is working for me (I use Makefile), can you create an answer, I accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can add a [LINK_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_DEPENDS.html) property to your executable target, using [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html). Add the following line after your `add_executable` command:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_DEPENDS ${LINKER_SCRIPT})
```

The first argument to `set_target_properties` is the target name, i.e. the first argument you passed to `add_executable`.

Comment: The problem is that cmake searching for `${LINKER_SCRIPT}` in build directory instead of in source directory. Actually I have solution to add `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${LINKER_SCRIPT}`

Comment: Or `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${LINKER_SCRIPT}` to search in the directory that the `add_executable` is defined in.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this mail](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-May/037206.html) which described three possible ways for forcing an executable to be dependent on a linker script. Its author prefers this way:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
PROJECT(LINKERSCRIPT C)
FILE(WRITE main.c "void main(){}")
# dummy.c must exist:
ADD_EXECUTABLE(EXE main.c dummy.c)
# linkerscript must exist:
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(
    dummy.c PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/linkerscript
)
```

Here `dummy.c` is an empty file, which is listed for the `add_executable()` command only for make resulted executable dependent on the linker script via the [OBJECT_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html) property.

Comment: Yes, I known about this solution with dummy.c file, but I don't think it is very elegant. For example if into Makefile I add empty target: `outupt.elf: linker.ln` beside linking target: `output.elf: main.o startup.o` then I get what I want, but I don't know how can I create an empty target with CMake, or if this is possible.

Comment: Yes, with direct using of Makefile, adding linker dependency is simpler and more elegant. But CMake doesn't allow adding dependencies for one file more than once. First time dependencies are added in `add_executable()` call, but all of them should be source or header files, so you cannot add linker-dependency at this stage. From the other side, you needn't to bother about Makefiles produced by CMake. They are much more complex than manually written files in any case.