# How to propagate file-level dependency (custom command + custom target) via interface library in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have a following scenario:

1. project I work on is mostly a static library
2. as this is an embedded project I also have linker scripts
3. each linker script requires some preprocessing before it can be used
4. static library, include paths, compiler flags and the linker flag to use preprocessed linker script are propagated to users via interface library.

This generally works fine, however there's only target-level dependency between user's application and preprocessed linker script (via interface library). There is no file-level dependency, so when I modify the source of the linker script, the preprocessed linker script gets regenerated, however user's application is not relinked.

Here's a test case

```
$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  dummy.c  linker-script.ld-source  main.c

$ cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(a_test)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT linker-script.ld
        COMMAND cmake -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/linker-script.ld-source linker-script.ld
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/linker-script.ld-source)
add_custom_target(linker-script DEPENDS linker-script.ld)

add_library(static-library STATIC
        dummy.c)

add_library(interface-library INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(interface-library INTERFACE
        # -Tlinker-script.ld
        static-library)
add_dependencies(interface-library linker-script)

add_executable(application
        main.c)
target_link_libraries(application interface-library)

$ cat main.c 
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

`dummy.c` and `linker-script.ld-source` are just empty. Generated linker script is not actually used, but the commended fragment shows how I intend to use it. Let's run it:

```
$ mkdir output

$ cd output

$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/cmake/output

$ make
Scanning dependencies of target static-library
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/static-library.dir/dummy.c.o
[ 40%] Linking C static library libstatic-library.a
[ 40%] Built target static-library
Scanning dependencies of target linker-script
[ 60%] Generating linker-script.ld
[ 60%] Built target linker-script
Scanning dependencies of target application
[ 80%] Building C object CMakeFiles/application.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable application
[100%] Built target application
```

OK, everything seems fine. Now let's say that source of linker script is updated:

```
$ touch ../linker-script.ld-source

$ make
[ 40%] Built target static-library
[ 60%] Generating linker-script.ld
[ 60%] Built target linker-script
[100%] Built target application
```

As you see, the application is not relinked and this is a problem here. Any ideas how such scenario could be solved?

Comment: I think `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` is more suitable for linker's option `-T<linker-script>` than `target_link_libraries` command. In that case, dependency on linker script could be created with `LINK_DEPENDS` target property, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138375/3440745). For add this property automatically, you may wrap `add_executable` into your macro/function. (Or you may define your `add_executable` macro/function, which calls original one).

Comment: @Tsyvarev - I would prefer (if possible) a solution which doesn't require any special behaviour from the users. If the user needs to do anything more than link my interface library, then I just don't need it at all and all the "modern CMake" cannot be applied to my scenario. If I have to provide my own wrapper for `add_executable`, then I can just use static library directly...

Answer (score 0):

The only proper solution (at least now) is to use [LINK_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/prop_tgt/LINK_DEPENDS.html) target property. For that I've added my own helper-function which looks like this:

```
#
# Specifies linker script(s) used for linking `target`.
#
# `distortosTargetLinkerScripts(target [linker-script.ld ...])`
#
# Most common use will be with single linker script provided by distortos:
# `distortosTargetLinkerScripts(target $ENV{DISTORTOS_LINKER_SCRIPT})`
#
# Proper linker flag is added, as well as CMake dependency via LINK_DEPENDS target property.
#

function(distortosTargetLinkerScripts target)
    foreach(linkerScript IN LISTS ARGN)
        target_link_libraries(${target} PRIVATE
                -T"${linkerScript}")
        get_target_property(linkDepends ${target} LINK_DEPENDS)
        if(NOT linkDepends)
            unset(linkDepends)
        endif()
        list(APPEND linkDepends "${linkerScript}")
        set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES
                LINK_DEPENDS "${linkDepends}")
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: There seems to be additional support coming up by adding a new target property for interface targets in CMake 3.13 ([`INTERFACE_LINK_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_DEPENDS.html) and updated doc for [`LINK_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/prop_tgt/LINK_DEPENDS.html) that mentions Ninja as a supported generator (Although, not sure when in which version of CMake was that feature was actually implemented).

---

*Note: Not a complete answer, but just documenting my uses with Ninja as generator*

Using `LINK_DEPENDS` does not work with non-`Makefile` generators, e.g. [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/).

My usual approach, out of those found in [this](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-May/037206.html) mailing list post, is to use a dummy file and modify its timestamp using

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT linker-script.ld
  [...]
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dummy.c
  [...])
```

Still, this does not work great since in the first invocation it detects that the linker script is out of date, and thus performs its copy and "touches" the dummy source file. However, a second invocation is required to pick up the modification and rebuild all the dependent targets.

This is inconvenient, but I believe it is routed in Ninja's categorization of dependencies (implicit, explicit, order-only). Using the `add_dependencies` command, creates only an order-only Ninja dependency, since the linker script does not affect in CMake terms the build line of the binary target that you want to run it with.

As for an [interface](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) library, I don't see how it would help in this situation, as it doesn't even create build output; it mostly acts like a organizational placeholder.

Comment: "Using LINK_DEPENDS does not work with non-Makefile generators, e.g. Ninja." - it works perfectly fine for me with Ninja. I won't post a shell dump, as in comment it would be completely unintelligible, but if you want I could paste it somewhere and share a link.

Comment: @FreddieChopin are you sure there's nothing else going on with the way you have set up your deps? Because this is also [documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_DEPENDS.html).

Comment: @FreddieChopin Ah, that's great. Thanks for that. I'll amend for that version of CMake once I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that may help

https://samthursfield.wordpress.com/2015/11/21/cmake-dependencies-between-targets-and-files-and-custom-commands/

See this part:

> 5. File-level dependencies of custom targets are not propagated

In short you need to add linker script dependency to library as well. Yes, this sucks.

```
add_dependencies(interface-library linker-script linker-script.ld-source)
```