# Let cmake re-link after link command file is changed

Tags: cmake

Here is my CMakeLists.txt. How to let cmake relink after linker command file is changed. There are two files, flash_addr.icf and linker.icf

CMakeLists.txt

```html
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(MODULE_NAME "TEST")

# Linker commmand files
set(FLASHER_SCRIPT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/flash_addr.icf")
set(LINKER_SCRIPT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/linker.icf")

# compiler and linker options
include(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/s32k14x_iar_config.cmake)

# source and header files
include(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include_list.cmake)
include(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source_list.cmake)


project("${MODULE_NAME}")

include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(${MODULE_NAME} ${INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SOURCE_DIRS})
```

found the solution in [CMAKE: How to add dependency on linker script for executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864689/cmake-how-to-add-dependency-on-linker-script-for-executable)

set_target_properties(${MODULE_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_DEPENDS ${LINKER_SCRIPT})
set_target_properties(${MODULE_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_DEPENDS ${FLASHER_SCRIPT})

Comment: Doesn't that work right after you change these variables?

Comment: Sorry, it works. But it does not work when link command file is changed. I have updated my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMAKE: How to add dependency on linker script for executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864689/cmake-how-to-add-dependency-on-linker-script-for-executable)