# Same sources, 2 different binaries with a linker script variable

Tags: cmake, linker

With CMake, I am trying to use the same sources and the same linker script to generate two different binaries.

```
/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 320K
FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = APP_ORIGIN, LENGTH = 0x40000
}
```

*APP_ORIGIN* is set as input in linker script, using *--defsym=APP_ORIGIN=VALUE*.

```
set(APP1_ORIGIN 0x0800C200)
set(APP2_ORIGIN 0x0804C200)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-T${LINKER_FILE} -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -specs=nano.specs -lc -lm -lnosys -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_NAME}.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections -Xlinker -print-memory-usage -Xlinker --defsym=APP_ORIGIN=${APP1_ORIGIN}")
```

The point is I **do not** know how to modify *CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS* with APP2_ORIGIN value and trigger link again.

This could be done with 2 different target, but if there is only one linker script, only have to maintain one, **because the application is exactly the same, only the offset varies**.

I tried with different approaches of POST_BUILD custom targets, but no success until now.

Comment: "The point is I know how to ..." - Do you mean instead "The point is I **do not** know how to ..."? Otherwise I see no **question** in your question post.

Comment: You are right, thanks, I do not know, will edit.

Comment: Since you want to have two different binaries, you need to create two **targets** (two `add_executable` calls). Per-target link options could be set via [target_link_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html) command, like in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55959247/cmake-how-to-specify-a-different-link-script-for-each-target). For compile sources once for both executables you could use OBJECT library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files are *generated* from input *template*.

Create a file `inputfile`:

```
/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 320K
FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = @APP_ORIGIN@, LENGTH = 0x40000
}
```

Then do:

```
configure_file(inputfile ${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/linkerscript1 @ONLY)
configure_file(inputfile ${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/linkerscript1 @ONLY)
```

Or alternatively the same with `add_custom_command` and a custom script.

And then do:

```
add_library(allobjectfiles all_your_files.c)  # maybe OBJECT library?
 
add_executable(yourtarget)
target_link_libraries(yourtarget allobjectfiles)
target_link_options(yourtarget PUBLIC
     -T${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/linkerscript1
)
set_target_properties(yourtarget PROPERTIES LINK_DEPENDS
     ${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/linkerscript1
)

# Repeat above for linkerscript2 with different target name
```