# CMake relink dynamic library on version script modification

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, ld

My dynamic library uses a version script to control exported symbols.
I want to create linkage dependency upon the `.version` file so the library relinks on a modification of the file.

I tried to do it using `PROPERTIES` as follows.

```
target_properties(so_lib
                  PROPERTIES
                  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/so_lib.version
                  LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,--version-script=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/so_lib.version"
                 )
```

This does not work. When I `touch` the file, library is not relinked, thus exported symbols are not updated to mirror the .version script definitions.

What is the best CMake practise for such a problem?

Comment: The property is named [LINK_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/LINK_DEPENDS.html), not `DEPENDS`. See also that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864689/cmake-how-to-add-dependency-on-linker-script-for-executable.