# CMake: dependecies of add_custom_command

Tags: cmake

Let's say I have a Python script which does something with just built executable. And I want CMake to rebuild that executable if the script was modified (actually it is enough to just re-run the script, but rebuild an executable is fine too).

```
add_executable(App src/main.cpp)

add_custom_command(
        TARGET App
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND "${Python3_EXECUTABLE}" ARGS "scripts/do_stuff.py" "$<TARGET_FILE:App>"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}"
)
```

How can I achieve that? add_custom_command with TARGET argument doesn't support DEPENDS argument. `add_dependency(App "scripts/do_stuff.py")` produces an error, because "scripts/do_stuff.py" is not a target, but just a file.

Running the script is very important for correct working of the executable so I don't want define completely separate target via `add_custom_command` allowing bypass script execution by building just `App` target.

Comment: "I want CMake to rebuild that executable if the script was modified" - Similar problem exists for a linker script. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864689/cmake-how-to-add-dependency-on-linker-script-for-executable) about resolving it. When you use `add_custom_command` as a *build event* (with `TARGET` parameter) the command doesn't control the dependencies.

Comment: The solution has worked for me `set_property(TARGET App APPEND PROPERTY LINK_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/scripts/do_stuff.py")` (I've replaced set_target_property to set_property to be able use APPEND)

Comment: As you say, "actually it is enough to just re-run the script", so `LINK_DEPENDS` isn't quite right. Unlike an actual _linker script_, the link step doesn't depend on your Python script. Instead, a custom target depends on both your script and the output of `app`.

Answer (score 1):

> actually it is enough to just re-run the script

So the executable does not depend on the script. So re-run the script, not the executable.

```
add_executable(app src/main.cpp)

add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/did_do_stuff
        COMMAND "${Python3_EXECUTABLE}" "scripts/do_stuff.py" "$<TARGET_FILE:app>"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/did_do_stuff
        DEPENDS "$<TARGET_FILE:app>"
                "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/scripts/do_stuff.py"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}"
)
add_custom_target(do_stuff
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/did_do_stuff
)
```

And build target `do_stuff` (or `all`) to run it.

Comment: I see the problem with IDEs, because they will suggest run an original executable, but in this case without running the script after link it won't work properly.